# How to segregate by one factor but colour by another in ggplot2 R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my dataset, I have segregated the data by a parameter `par` for either `Black` or `Red` noise that are staggered in represtation. Now, for both species, I want to colour the "Black" noise as black, and "Red" as red. Furthermore, I want to join the points by `par` -- specifically, I want to join `par` -- `No` with a Dashed line, and `Yes` as a solid line. I tried the piece of code attached (and multiple versions of it)..but no luck. Any suggestions?

```
#Data

set.seed(100)
sp <- factor(c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"))
par <- factor(c("No","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","Yes","Yes"))
y <- rnorm(8, 2,3)
noise <- factor(c("Black","Red","Black","Red","Black","Red","Black","Red"))

df <- data.frame(sp, par, y, noise)
df$noise <- factor(df$noise, levels = c("Black","Red"))
```

[image]

```
  library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(data = df, aes(x = noise, y = y, fill = par, color = par)) +
      geom_point(size = 4) + 
      facet_wrap(.~sp) +
      theme_classic() + 
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("black","red")) +   scale_color_manual(values = c("black","red")) +  
      geom_line(aes(linetype=par)) + scale_linetype_manual(name = "indicator", values = c(2,1,2))
      geom_path(aes(group = par,linetype=par), geom = "path")
```

ERROR: geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you forget to add a `+` to link `geom_path()` with the `ggplot()`. Since the `aes()` of `geom_point()` and `geom_path()` doesn't match, you'll need to include them in the corresponding `geom_*()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = noise, y = y, group = par, linetype = par)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = noise, color = noise, ), size = 4) + 
  facet_wrap(.~sp) +
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black","red")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black","red")) +  
  geom_line() + 
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "indicator", values = c(2,1,2)) +
  geom_path()
```

[image: geom_group]

Comment: This is great! It really helps with the Part 2. I'm still stuck on the Part 1. For either treatment, I need the points corresponding to "Black" as black and "Red" as Red. I tried to change it in aes in line 1 but it gives me an error `Error: geom_path: If you are using dotted or dashed lines, colour, size and linetype must be constant over the line`

Comment: And the line joining par "Yes" as a black solid line

Comment: Sorry I missed you part 1, see if my edited answer fits what you want.